# Threading in python(multi-threading)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

If I have 7 methods and 2 threads. Method 1 and Method 2 need to be executed by the 2 threads(Thread 1, Thread2 ). Depending on which thread completes first.Eg: If thread 2 finishes execution first it should pick method 3 for execution and thread 1 should pick up method 4 and it should continue the same till all 7 methods are executed.  Is there a way to accomplish this? Any reference would be highly appreciated

Comment: What about methods 4..7?

Comment: ** Updated the description

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply put the methods in a queue and let two threads compete for executing the methods:

```py
import threading, queue

def worker(q):
    while True:
        method = q.get()
        if not method:
            return
        method()

q = queue.Queue()

methods = [m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7]

for method in methods:
    q.put(method)

threads = [threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q,)) for _ in range(2)]

for thread in threads:
    q.put(None)  # include a terminating signal for each thread
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the queue-based solution from the other answer, you can use the excellent `concurrent.futures` module to do the heavy lifting for you:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
    for m in methods:
        pool.submit(m)
```

The `submit()` method on the thread pool submits the task to the pool and returns a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object (not to be confused with the asyncio type of the same name) that allows you to query whether a particular task is done, wait for it to finish, and pick up the result.

If you don't do any of that, the `with` block will automatically wait for all the submitted tasks to finish at the end of the block.

Answer (score 1):

The answer submitted by @user4815162342 is certainly a simple way to go, but I thought I would show you the equivalent way with the `multiprocessing.pool` module:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

with ThreadPool(2) as pool:
    for m in methods:
        pool.apply_async(m)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The `apply_asyc` method returns an `AsyncResult` object whose `get` method can be called to await the completion of the submitted "task" and to get the return value if the methods you are calling return anything of interest. Otherwise, calling `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` will block until all submitted tasks complete. If the methods did return values you were interested in, then you should save the `AsyncResult` objects returned by `apply_async` and call `get` on them instead. In that case there is no real need anymore to call `close` and `join`:

```py
with ThreadPool(2) as pool:
    results = [pool.apply_async(m) for m in methods]
    return_values = [result.get() for result in results]
```

At the end of the `with` block, <strike>all the threads in the pool are terminated</strike> along with any tasks that have been submitted, i.e. `pool.terminate()` is implicitly called (unlike the `concurrent.futures` module where outstanding tasks' completions are awaited).

**Clarification**

There are two parallel classes, one for a process pool:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
# or from multiprocessinf.pool import Pool
```

And one for a thread pool:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
# or from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

They are supposed to have the same API's (and, in fact, they do). However, `pool.terminate()` cannot in the case of a thread pool actually terminate threads as there is no method for killing threads. So if the thread is already running a submitted task at the time `pool.terminate()` is called either explicitly or implicitly, it may continue to run.